# Geometry Question about Circles

Tags: geometry

[image: Drawing]

**Given:** MJ = NK, CK=KD, AJ=JB

**Prove:** AB=CD

Thank You!

Comment: I don't have a direction, I'd be happy to hear one

Comment: Shouldn't this be obvious by a symmetry argument?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the drawing, we observe a striking symmetry in it which (if proved formally) would prove the claim.

Now, let's do it formally:

Let $d$ be the line perpendicular to $MN$ and going through $O$.

Let $f(X)$ be the reflection of a point with respect to $d$.

Clearly, $d$ passes through the midpoint of $MN$ and hence of $JK$ thus $f(M)=N, f(N)=M, f(J)=K, f(K)=J$.

We now look at the points $X=f(C), Y=f(D)$.

They are both on the circle and their midpoint is $J$.

Also the line $JO$ is perpendicular to $XY$ since $OX=OY$.

But then $X,Y,A,B$ are collinear and thus $X=A, Y=B$ i.e.
$f(C)=A, f(D)=B$.

But since the length of line segments remains invariant under such a reflection this proves $$|\overline{CD}|=|\overline{f(C)f(D)}|=|\overline{AB}|$$

Comment: A very thorough and formal proof, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry of your given figure $ AJ = CK, AB/2 = CD/2, \rightarrow AB =CD.$